# stealing the provisional patent application

Tags: inventorship, us20120221930

Please, I want to question is it possible exposure to stealing the provisional patent application? If presented to companies through NOLO Company or other, And whether enough contract agreement to prevent a violation of rights?
      Note: I am a foreigner
          Best regards

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely unlikely that such a company would try to "steal" your application or the underlying IP. However, DO NOT file a patent application with Nolo or any other cut-rate self-directed services.

The problem with these Nolo, LegalZoom or other cheap patent services, and the like is, that they lure inventors into believing that they can get solid patent protection for cheap. In fact, the sad reality is that patent applications drafted this way offer effectively no patent protection and have little chance of withstanding the examination process. Plus, the nature of the patent system makes it such that inventors won’t know this until it’s too late and their patent rights are irrevocably lost.

The following blog post discusses the perils of LegalZoom in great detail: http://www.patentsdemystified.com/is-it-safe-to-use-legalzoom-to-file-a-patent-application/

It would be best to talk with a patent attorney about this before doing anything. Typically, you can find one who will give you a free consultation.